# Can I dynamically take a Html element onclick attribute and use it in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

```
    <input  type="button" onclick="???"    id="1" value="Button1"   />
```

Without knowing what the name of the function in the onclick attribute, can I take the function from the onclick attribute and call it in javascript? If so, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to trigger click event which will call the onclick function, you can do something like this, using jquery

```
$('#1').click()
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work, NOTE: **IDs are not allowed to start with a number**:

```
<input  type="button" onclick="???"    id="Button1 value="Button1"   />

document.getElementById("Button1").onclick();
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/9EJ6m/)

The way to do it in jQuery would be `$('#Button1').trigger('click')` using [**trigger**](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery:

```
eval($('#1').attr('onclick'));
```